# windows 10 change localhost to another host in hosts file，why it's not available?

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10, hosts

1. I change localhost to 192.168.1.222
   [image]
2. flush dns `ipconfig /flushdns`
3. `ping localhost`
   [image]
4. but it's not available，why? thanks

I hope, localhost can resovled to anthor host, and when I visit http://localhost in chrome, it can also resolve to the host that I changed

Comment: Please try this. `ping -4 localhost`